# Jquery Sortable still serializing item after its removed

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a number of connectedSortable lists, i have also created a waste bin `<div>` that can recieve an item that is dropped onto (with the `drop:` event) it which is great.

This item is then removed from the database.

The problem i have is that when an item is dropped into the bin and removed from the database the `stop:` event fires on the the list that has now changed since the item was removed. The stop event serializes the list of item id's and updates the database with the new order. However it is still serializing the id that was removed.

e.g.

```
<li id="1">Item 1</li>
<li id="2">Item 2</li>
<li id="3">Item 3</li>
<li id="4">Item 4</li>
```

Then if i drag `item 1` into the bin the serialized data after the sort is:

```
item[]:1 //shouldn't be serialized
item[]:2
item[]:3
item[]:4
```

my waste bin ajax is:

```
$('.wastebin').droppable({
  accept: 'li',
  helper  : 'clone',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var data = $.param({order: ui.helper.attr("data-order")});
    data += '&'+ $.param({dpmt_id: ui.helper.attr("data-dpmt")});
    data += '&'+ $.param({pjct_id: ui.helper.attr("data-pjct")});
    console.log("Binned: " + data);

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url : "project_tasks.php?task=delete_project",
     data: data,
     success: function(){
       toastr["success"]("Project has been deleted!");
       ui.helper.remove();
     },
     error: function(){
      toastr["Warning"]("Failed to delete project.");
     }
   });
  }
});
```

stop event:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    var dpmt = $(this).data('dpmt');
    ui.item.attr('data-dpmt', dpmt);

    data += '&'+ $.param({dpmt_id: $(this).data('dpmt')});
    data += '&'+ $.param({pjct_id: ui.item.data('pjct')});
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url : "project_tasks.php?task=update_ordering",
      data: data,
      success: function(){
        toastr["success"]("New order updated");
      }
    })
});
```

I'm still finding my feet with jQuery so it's drobably just me missing something silly.

Thanks